# Google get email proper scopes

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace, google-signin, google-oauth-java-client

A lot of the documentation on google talks about the `email` scope to replace the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`, pared with the endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me`. Documentation found here https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email.
Yet there is more documentation that states even that is being replaced in favor of the plus api and endpoint and the `people.get` endpoint. Documentation found here https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#email.
I have an application that needs to request the user email for both authentication and to verify they have installed our app.. A bonus is when I try to add the `email` scope to the developer console, or use it in my app, it tells me that `email` is not a valid scope.
My question is what are the proper scopes that need be applied in my app and in the google developer console? Need to be sure of this since the Google Apps Marketplace V2 has rules about prompting users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the "email+profile" scope. That's the only way you will comply with the marketplace requirements to hide the user consent window.

Don't worry about the API console saying this is not a valid scope, it works when you provide it to the OAuth endpoint.

Here's [an explanatory blog post](http://david-codes.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-provide-seamless-single-sign-on.html) with a sample in Java and all the required configuration steps.

Comment: Hi David - when you say email+profile scope - we define this as 2 separate scopes - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email.  what would be the URL for your email+profile scope?

Comment: That's not a url. That's just two scopes respectively called "email" and "profile". Just try it or try the test project that I link up in my blog article.

Comment: Thanks for the answer David, what endpoint are you using to get their info? I have been using `https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me` but they state that its being replaced by `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userId}`.

Comment: You do not need an endpoint, the info is provided in the OAuth answer. See the blog article and code example for more info.